# Combining multiple data files with header while also adding a data column

Tags: bash, shell

I have multiple tab delimited data files that are separated by month in the format `jan06.txt, feb06.txt, ..., dec07.txt`.

Within each file, it looks something like:

```
Header1 Header2 Header3 ...
Data1   Data2   Data3   ...
Data4   Data5   Data6   ...
...     ...     ...
```

What I want to do is to combine all all the data files into a single data file, with just a single header at the top, but also include a new data column that contains the month and year so I don't lose that information from the file name. So my new, single data file would contain:

```
Date   Header1 Header2 Header3 ...
200601 Data1   Data2   Data3   ...
200602 Data4   Data5   Data6   ...
...    ...     ...     ...
```

Where 200601 would refer to Jan 06, 200602 refer to Feb 06, etc.

I know if I do something like `cat *.txt > data.txt`, I could combine all my files. However, the two issues remain:

1. I have a header in every file that would get concatenated, which I don't want.
2. I would lose the month information that is stored in the file name.

I think I can do this with some combination of `cat` and `sed`, but I am not sure how to start.

Comment: Also asked on [superuser](http://superuser.com/q/545315/4714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
function month() {

    case ${1:0:3} in
        "jan") echo "20${1:3:2}01" ;;
        "feb") echo "20${1:3:2}02" ;;
        "mar") echo "20${1:3:2}03" ;;
        "apr") echo "20${1:3:2}04" ;;
        "may") echo "20${1:3:2}05" ;;
        "jun") echo "20${1:3:2}06" ;;
        "jul") echo "20${1:3:2}07" ;;
        "aug") echo "20${1:3:2}08" ;;
        "sep") echo "20${1:3:2}09" ;;
        "oct") echo "20${1:3:2}10" ;;
        "nov") echo "20${1:3:2}11" ;;
        "dec") echo "20${1:3:2}12" ;;
    esac

}

# Header
directory="your_directory/"
echo -en "Date\t" > data.txt
head -1 $(ls "${directory}"/*.txt | head -1) >> data.txt

# Contents
for file in "${directory}"/*.txt; do

    date="${file##*/}"
    date="$(month ${date%*.txt})\t"
    tail -n +2 ${file} | sed 's/^/'${date}'/' >> data.txt

done
```

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
 echo -e 'Date\tHeader1\tHeader2\tHeader3 ...' >out
 sed -n -e 's/^/200601\t/' -e '2,$p' <jan06.txt >>out
 sed -n -e 's/^/200602\t/' -e '2,$p' <feb06.txt >>out
```

etc.

Comment: Or `sed -n -e '2,$s/^/200601\t/p'` (where the `-e` is now optional)?